# Jquery auto fill check box when dropdown option is selected

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, loops

I have a form which is dynamically populated from a database. using a while loop to display the results. I have a status drop down with three options which change the status of an order. The user then has to select a checkbox to email the status of an order to another user based on the selection which is made. This currently works, however I would like to automate this process by setting the checkbox to true once an option in the drop down has been selected, instead of manually clicking the checkbox. My code which generates these results looks like:

```
echo '<select id="order_status" name="order_status['.$i.']" id="id" onchange="showUser(this.value)" >';
    echo '<option value = "Pending"   name="order_status['.$i.']" class = "pending"' . ($row['status'] == 'Pending' ? ' selected=selected' : '') . '>Pending</option>';
    echo '<option value = "Approved"  name="order_status['.$i.']" class = "approved"' . ($row['status'] == 'Approved' ? ' selected=selected' : '') . '>Approved</option>';
    echo '<option value = "Disapproved" name="order_status['.$i.']" class ="disapproved"' . ($row['status'] == 'Disapproved' ? ' selected=selected' : '') . '>Disapproved</option>';
    echo '</select>';
    echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="order_selected['.$i.']"/></td>';
    echo '</td>';
```

Where order_status contains the select values, and order selected contains the checkbox which is selected by a user. If the checkbox is set to true then an email will be sent to the user, updating them on the status of the order. I would like to do this frontend as the value of the checkbox does not need to be permanently set. My main problem is knowing what order has been selected, ensuring the correct checkbox is set to true.

Many Thanks

Comment: It appears your `<select>` tag has two `id` attributes.  This would cause problems, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

I would get rid of the onchange attribute in the select tag

```
echo '<select id="order_status" name="order_status['.$i.']" id="id">';
echo '<option value = "Pending"   name="order_status['.$i.']" class = "pending"' . ($row['status'] == 'Pending' ? ' selected=selected' : '') . '>Pending</option>';
echo '<option value = "Approved"  name="order_status['.$i.']" class = "approved"' . ($row['status'] == 'Approved' ? ' selected=selected' : '') . '>Approved</option>';
echo '<option value = "Disapproved" name="order_status['.$i.']" class ="disapproved"' . ($row['status'] == 'Disapproved' ? ' selected=selected' : '') . '>Disapproved</option>';
echo '</select>';
echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="order_selected['.$i.']"/></td>';
echo '</td>';
```

Then handle it all with jQuery

```
$(document).on('change', 'id', function() {
    if (this.value == "Pending") { //Change to whatever should auto check the box
        $("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", true);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. This is great and similar to the implementation I have however this is selecting all checkboxes with the input type of 'checkbox' and not individual orders. is it possible to wrap this in a loop?

Comment: You could select the checkbox by the name attribute, it should be unique to each select.